# I need to install Inkscape on an Ubuntu Server. Do I need to install x11?

Tags: xorg, inkscape

The PHP charting solution we use for a web application has a means of allowing user to download HTML5 charts/graphs as PDF or PNG etc... but uses Inkscape and ImageMagik to render. Normally Inkscape is GUI program, however our solution would use it from CLI only. Does anyone know whether X11 libraries are required by Inkscape?

Answer (score 1):

According to the [wiki](http://wiki.inkscape.org/wiki/index.php/Tracking_Dependencies) Inkscape depends on GTK, which could depend on X11, but I am not sure. You could try running the following command to simulate installing it:

```
sudo apt-get install -s inkscape
```

See if it would pull down some X11 packages.

Comment: That's true... Totally forgot about the -s option.

Comment: also, the simulate option does not need sudo - this makes it even safer.

Answer (score 0):

Both Inkscape, and ImageMagick from the repositories depend on X11. You therefore won't be able to install them from there without also installing X11 as a dependency.

ImageMagick can amongst other options also be [compiled without X11](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/advanced-unix-installation.php) dependency for manual installation.